# Can someone explain what the 'r' object for is doing in the following code sample?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet, I understand the logic for the most part, but I'm confused as to the placement of the r that is being passed in the buildRegister function.

```
function register (tileName, config) {

    if (!config) {config = {};}
    var r = {};
    for (var k in services)
    {
        buildRegister (services [k] (tileName, config), r);
    }
    return r;
  }
```

Comment: `buildRegister` isn't built in JavaScript function, so you should attach the code for it and its dependencies as well. Also if you used any 3rd party js packages, you should put them in the post tags.

Comment: its simply a storage object,  buildRegister takes some parameters, of which r is one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, buildRegister is populating r based on the other parameters as it loops through the services array. Remember that in JavaScript, an object parameter is represented by a reference to the object, so modifying the object from within a function causes the same object in the calling context to be modified.

By the end of the loop, r will have been populated and ready to be returned by the register function.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain that in a more simple way?

Comment: @Kunal Ojha: r is the register, buildRegister builds r (exactly as it says on the tin), register then returns r after it has been built. That's about as simple as it gets.